# How to change a MS Acess database into a MySql database or atleast move the data across quickly?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I created a program that stores the scores of a competition into a MS Access database but now I need to change in to use MySql. How can I transfer all the tables and data across?

Comment: Are you using a particular program to manage your MySQL instance, or are you doing everything by hand in the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in bulk is to right click on the tables in MS Access and select `Export > Text File`. This will allow you to save each table as a csv file.

Once you've done that, you can use whatever management program you're using to *import* the csv files. If you're using MySQL's [workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html), this tutorial should help you. If you want to do it manually, [this one](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/) should help.